# calculating TF-IDF for words in documents in solr and java

Tags: java, solr, nlp, tf-idf

I can easily get the TF by counting the number of Term in a document 
and i want to know how to calculate document frequency,
i.e. the number of documents that contain this term

What I've reached so far is querying solr with a large number of rows and counting the results  back , but this is very Time and memory expensive . I want to count the terms only

```
    SolrQuery q = new SolrQuery();
    q.setQuery("tweet_text:"+kw);
    q.addField("tweet_text");
    q.setRows(40000000);        
    SolrDocumentList results = null ;

    try {
        QueryResponse rsp = solrServer.query(q);
        results = rsp.getResults();
    } catch (SolrServerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ArrayList<String> tweets = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (SolrDocument doc : results)
    {
        tweets.add(doc.getFieldValue("tweet_text").toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In SOLR, you can use a function query to query docFreq directly, shown here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#docfreq,

```
q={!func}docFreq(tweet_text, kw)
```

Note, also documented on that page are function query methods to get tf, idf and termfreq, which may also be helpful for you.

---

*This is probably less relevant to this question*, in retrospect, but I'll leave it for the time being in case it is useful to you.

[IndexReader.docFreq(Term)](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#docFreq(org.apache.lucene.index.Term)) could get you what you're looking for.

such as:

```
reader.docFreq(new Term("tweet_text", kw));'
```

IndexSearcher.docFreq(Term) is the same thing, by the way.

Comment: and to access the IndexReader object i should first include the 
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;
and the apache lucene jars  ?

Comment: Wasn't paying as close attention to how you were searching as I probably should have.  I think you should probably just send a function query to get that.  I've ammended by answer to reflect this.

Comment: i constructed this Query 
http://localhost:8983/solr/db/select?
defType=func&q=docfreq(tweet_text,'@')

searching for doc freq of '@' character
when i open this url i can't find docfreq in the result

the result : http://pastie.org/5407275

Comment: i found that i should show field called 'score' in the field list

this works 

http://localhost:8983/solr/db/ select?fl=score&defType=func&q=docfreq(tweet_text,'@')